# Alternative panel for a custom compiz session for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, panel, alternative

I really don't want to use any existing DE out there, so I have decided to put together custom compiz session with probably a dock such as dockbarx or docky. Now I just need a decent panel to use, I remeber I could use the unity-2d-panel but not anymore since its dropped from 12.10. Any suggestions? So far I have tried tint2, xfce4-panel, and wingpanel.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question. You say you don't wanna use a existing DE, but you would use unity-2d-panel if it wouldn't have been dropped from 12.10?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding  I am looking for a panel with indicators like a system tray, it's not that the unity-2d-panel was my preference just that it worked pretty well.

Comment: If you just want an oldschool-panel you could give `Gnome 3 in Fallbackmode` a try.

Comment: thanks yes I tried that I just though maybe someone knew of some panel I didn't know of. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you:

- Docky: The most simple, but really good
- Cairo-dock: a complete dock that provide a session himself
- Avant Window Navigator: in the middle between the previous

I suggest you try all three

Comment: I believe AWN was dropped from 12.10 repositories. I'm sorry if I didn't clarify I need a system tray, so docky is not it but cairo dock always seemed to look very "cartoon" like. thanks though